# Passing parameters after creating ReWrite Rule

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

Does anyone know how i can stop variables from being lost after creating a Rewrite Rule?
Putting in [QSA] gives me a Server 500 error message

I want this rule

```
RewriteRule ^family-name/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ family-name.php?familyName=$1&token=$2 [L]
```

and this works in the sense of i get

> family-name.php/somthing/token

However, when i go to `$_GET['familyName']` or token it returns blank. why?

Note. the ReWrite rule is in my .htaccess page

UPDATE:

I have reduced my code down to this:

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteRule ^my-family/family-name/([a-z]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ my-family/family- 
name.php?familyName=$1&token=$2 [QSA,L,NC]`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

`RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ $1.php [NC,L]`

My parameters are being passed through onto the next page LOCALLY ONLY and not when uploaded to my live site. Any thoughts???

Comment: Check your server error log, why you get error 500 ?

Comment: Ok, am now no longer seeing this error 500!!! Anywho, parameters are still not being passed. On the next page i have:

 if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ Do something }; its not doing it

Comment: Correction: if(isset($_GET['familyName'])){ do something };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should open page (with your domain name).

```
http://example.com/family-name/something/token
```

And call your parameters with `$_GET['token']`, not `$_SESSION['token']`.

If you want `RewriteRule` for

```
http://example.com/family-name.php/something/token
```

You should have:

```
RewriteRule ^family-name.php/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ family-name.php?familyName=$1&token=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I found the issue the same time you posted this. I was missing the full path like you said. Thank you for your time to reply.

Comment: I did but as i'm new it said i cannot - sorry

Comment: You already did. Thanks! Have fun with programming and on SO.

Comment: Hmmmm, it works offline (local host) but not online and yes i did change my path
`RewriteRule ^https://strictlyfamily.com/my-family/family-name/([a-z]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ https://strictlyfamily.com/my-family/family-name.php?familyName=?$1&familyCode=$2 [NC,QSA,L]`
Parameters not being passed onto next page

Comment: Their is a typo in your Rule. You can check rules on this pages before implementing: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Where? That site said This rule was not met but doesnt say why

Comment: Try this `RewriteRule ^my-family/family-name/([a-z]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ my-family/family-name.php?familyName=$1&familyCode=$2 [NC,QSA,L]`

Comment: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=2fde820b-ec9c-580e-bf09-1e5f6eee4928

Comment: Still the same, not passing anything through

Comment: Ok but it's only half complete. Issue still stands

Comment: It's complete. You pass something different and you even don't follow my tips. SO is not for doing job for you but helping to get you understanding.

Comment: RewriteRule ^family-name.php/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ family-name.php?familyName=$1&token=$2 [L] This also only works locally

Comment: There must problem with your server configuration, not mod-rewrite.